# Adding Subfolders to a Folder with Wildcard Directory Name

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to add subfolders with the same Name to multiple Folders which currently have the following structure:

```
V:/fixed name/ABC/fixed Name/
```

where the "ABC" is a changing combination of three letters.

I found the following code, but it is unable to accept my "*" Wildcard for the "ABC".

```
FOR /d %A IN (V:/fixed name/ABC/fixed Name/) DO mkdir "%A\14c"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
nickma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line:

```
FOR /D %A IN ("V:\fixed name\*") DO mkdir "%A\fixed name\14c"
```

In a batch file:

```
FOR /D %%A IN ("V:\fixed name\*") DO mkdir "%%A\fixed name\14c"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, that doesn't fix my Problem: I have a fixed Name, then a Wildcard, then a fixed Name for the directory, in which I want to add the subfolder. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: I tested it on the same directory structure you detailed. For me it was "Test Folder\ABC\fixed name\14c". Are you sure this is what you have and it didn't work?

Comment: Now I tested it with the *exact* same directory names you listed here and copy/pasted my answer. It created the directories just fine. You can see the results [here](https://pastebin.com/WsrdxVtw).

Comment: Note that the `mkdir` commands were not typed manually; the `FOR` loop created them. If you put it in a batch script and precede it with an @ sign or set `ECHO` to `OFF` then it won't show the commands it generates and runs.

Comment: I just tried again and it actually worked out, although I don't know why it didn't work in the first place... Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sure thing. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

This will work but only ONE '*' is allowed:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set pre=
set post=
set pattern=%~1
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=*" %%p in ("%pattern%") do (
   set pre=%%p
   set post=%%q
)
pushd %pre%
for /f %%d in ('dir /b /ad') do @md %%d%post% && echo added: %%d%post%
popd
```

The path before the wildcard must exist. Here, we look for all folders (= wildcard) and append the path which follows the wildcard argument. This could be a folder tree as well (`mkwild C:\users\me\test\*\first\second`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I am very new to this Topic, how can I define the directory in the code you provided? My directory only Needs one Wildcard, so I think your solution might work if I can get it entered ;)

Comment: Just call this batch file with one argument. Like `mkwild.cmd fixedpath\*\newfolder` which will create one folder `newfolder` below each folder in `fixedpath`. Enclose the argument in "..." if it contains blanks.

Comment: Thanks again. I created a Batch file with the code you provided, saved it and tried to call the file with mkwild.cmd fixedpath\*\newfolder. However, I Keep getting an error message back that the file does not exist...

Comment: did you name the batch file "mkwild.cmd"? Does "fixedpath" exist? Please note that the correct argument would be "fixedpath\*\newfolder", i.e. with 2 backslashes.

Comment: Yes, I did. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work? :/

Comment: Nice idea for a script for repeated use. =) If you want to make it work with multiple wildcards, consider recursing into the same script (or batch function) in your loop instead, and if the given path doesn't contain any wildcards then create the directory.

Comment: the script takes only one argument, namely the path to create, containing an asterisk. So, if saved as 'mkwild.cmd', calling 'mkwild c:\temp\\*\added' will create folders named 'added' under each folder in 'c:\temp'.